# How to mount 8TB external NTFS drive?

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I'm trying to do something that I think is fairly simple, but it doesn't want to work. I have an 8TB Easystore that I've been using to store media on for a while (from a windows computer, it was my F:\ drive). I now want to access that media through a plex server on my Ubuntu server (Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS). I've tried

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sdb1 /media/external
```

but to no avail. It returns

```
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory

ntfs-3g 2015.3.14AR.1 integrated FUSE 28 - Third Generation NTFS Driver
                Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on

Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2015 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009 Erik Larsson

Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]] <device|image_file> <mount_point>

Options:  ro (read-only mount), windows_names, uid=, gid=,
          umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
          Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).

Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

News, support and information:  http://tuxera.com
```

This is confusing to me, on top of the fact that fdisk -l shows

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.3 TiB, 8001562869760 bytes, 15628052480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x459f6879

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Any advice on how to accomplish this simple task?

Edit: here's the result of sudo gdisk /dev/sdb -l

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v' to
verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to repair
the disk.
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
Disk /dev/sdb: 15628052480 sectors, 7.3 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 2D532CC8-16B4-4C21-8EF7-6210D3D90924
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 15628053134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2669 sectors (1.3 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              34          262177   128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   2          264192     15628052479   7.3 TiB     0700  Basic data partition
```

Edit2: Result of sudo lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 136.7G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0 128.7G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

edit3: sudo gdisk v and w results:

```
 v

Caution: The CRC for the backup partition table is invalid. This table may
be corrupt. This program will automatically create a new backup partition
table when you save your partitions.

Problem: The secondary header's self-pointer indicates that it doesn't reside
at the end of the disk. If you've added a disk to a RAID array, use the 'e'
option on the experts' menu to adjust the secondary header's and partition
table's locations.

Problem: Disk is too small to hold all the data!
(Disk size is 15628052480 sectors, needs to be 15628053168 sectors.)
The 'e' option on the experts' menu may fix this problem.

Problem: GPT claims the disk is larger than it is! (Claimed last usable
sector is 15628053134, but backup header is at
15628053167 and disk size is 15628052480 sectors.
The 'e' option on the experts' menu will probably fix this problem

Caution: Partition 1 doesn't begin on a 8-sector boundary. This may
result in degraded performance on some modern (2009 and later) hard disks.

Consult http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/
for information on disk alignment.

Identified 4 problems!

And w

Caution! Secondary header was placed beyond the disk's limits! Moving the
header, but other problems may occur!

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
33 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Aborting write of new partition table.
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1050997/edit) your question and add the output of `sudo lsblk`

Comment: Just did, also tried mounting sdb2, still 'No such file or directory' .

Comment: Sorry, I missed this part here `GPT: damaged`.  When using `gdisk` you will have to make sure that the partitions are viewable like it shows there, then press `w` so it should write out a new partition table.   As it shows right now, it is not seeing any partitions.  The GPT needs to be fixed.

Comment: Will this delete all the files currently on the drive? I need the data to remain intact unless that's entirely not possible.

Comment: `gdisk` can actually see the partitions as it loaded that from backup.  As long as you don't do a sector by sector low level format of the drive, or format it and start writing new data to it, then your data will remain intact and can be recovered if the partition table corrupts completely.  Right now, I really don't see any other option here other than to write out the new partition table in `gdisk` that it pulled from backup.  Also, while in `gdisk` maybe press `v` to verify the integrity before writing out the partition table.

Comment: Tried gdisk v and w, posted the results above. Guess I need to do some partition resizing. At this point though it almost might be easier to just make it a network drive on my windows machine and mount that...

Comment: That always is a possibility that Windows might have done some security on the drive to make it unreadable by other OSes.  If it does work in Windows, then go with that.